# awk how to compare two columns for loop

Tags: bash, awk

This is `awk` command and file:

```
awk -v qt="'" -v host="${HOSTNAME,,}" '
FNR==NR         { if (FNR>=4) {
                    split($0,a,"[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*")
                    split(a[2],b,"=")
                    plans[b[2]] = a[2]
                    ip[a[8]]
                }
                next
                }

/value:/ { custom_value = $2 }
{ split($0,c,qt)

                    if ( (host == "hostnameA") || (host == "hostnameB") ) {
                        if (custom_value in plans)
                        printf "ID == %s and IP == %s\n", custom_value, ip
                    }
                    else if ( (host == "hostnameC") || (host == "hostnameD") ) {
                        if (custom_value in plans)
                        printf "ID == %s and IP == %s\n", custom_value, ip
                    }
                    else { print "other" }
                }
' list.txt ids.yaml
```

This is `list.txt`:

```
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------+----------+-------------+
| ID                                   | Name                       | Status  | Networks    | Image    | Flavor      |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------------------------+-------------+
| a4594fa2-5867-4fb1-b0d6-48833a750f10 | serverA                    | ACTIVE  | IP=1.1.1.1  | Debian11 | Airo B30G23 |
| 314d0d30-0836-4816-be75-310069d9c6ea | server B                   | ACTIVE  | IP=2.2.2.2  | Ubuntu20 | IAV B50C24  |
| 4c82f347-b0a6-471d-87d2-59bdd1d0bae4 | server C.me                | ACTIVE  | IP=3.3.3.3  | Ubuntu20 | IAV B50C48  |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------------------------+-------------+
```

This is `ids.yaml`:

```
    value: a4594fa2-5867-4fb1-b0d6-48833a750f10
    value: f19e0fb2-1744-41be-a3d9-0fa03325246c
    value: 72e50347-886d-4ab2-8363-1d052f5dd02c
```

I should note that the `awk` command is not written by me, but based on the comments for the above code, I tried to change it based on my requirements.

The expected output is:

```
ID == a4594fa2-5867-4fb1-b0d6-48833a750f10 and IP == 1.1.1.1
```

But when I run my awk command, I have no output.

I am trying to save the variables correctly, but I can't understand where's the issue.

I'm saving variables like `ids_value` which is second column of first file, and `custom_value` which is second column of second file, and saving IPs into `ip`, but `printf` returns nothing.

**Update 1**

This is also a simple version of the above code to print and check if the code prints the correct values, which does not.

```
awk -v qt="'" '
FNR==NR
    { if (FNR>=4) {
        split($0,a,"[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*")
        ids_value[b[2]] = a[2]
        ip[a[8]]
    }
        next
    }

/value:/ { custom_value = $2 }
{

    printf "%s\n", ip
}
' list.txt ids.yaml
```

**Update 2**

This prints the ID, but no IP:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2,$2];next} ($2,$2) in a' list.txt ids.yaml
```

Comment: *`when I run my awk command, I have no output`* - when I run your code I get 3 lines of 'other`

Comment: you don't seem to understand how `split()` works nor what's stored in the resulting array, eg, `a[2]`, `b[2]` and `a[8]` don't contain the values that you think they do; couple suggestions: *a)* review [(GNU) awk string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) for details on how `split()` works and *b)* add some debugging code to your script to see the results of the `split()` calls (eg, after a `split(...,a,...)` run `print NR,FNR,$0; for (i in a) print i,a[i]` - replace 'a' with 'b' or 'c' based on your `split()` calls);

Comment: as for the 2nd set of code ... *a)* the condition (eg, `FNR==NR`) must be followed (on the same line) by at least the opening `{`, so the line `FNR==NR` says to print each line from the first file to stdout; what you need to do is (at a minimum) move the opening `{` up to the same line (ie, `FNR==NR {` ... *b)* as written the `{ if (FNR>=4) {...} next }` is applied to all lines of input, ie, after reading each line you hit `next` so nothing else in the script is ever executed (moving the leading `{` up to the `FNR==NR` line should get you past this issue) ...

Comment: *c)* `b[2]` is referencing a non-existent array named `b` (`awk` will replace `b[2]` with a blank` - probably not what you want)

Comment: (for both files) ... *d)* `ip[a[8]]` vs `ip` : `p` is being referenced as both a scalar and an array - this will generate an error (once the other issues are fixed) - `p` cannot be both a scaler and array; looking at your previous Q&A's (that this code is based on) it appears you've been a bit inconsistent when changing variable names, ie, you changed `ip = $2` to `custom_value = $2` but failed to change `ip` to `custom_value` elsewhere in the script; as for `ip[a[8]]` ... this is something new you've added for some unknown reason (and `a[8]` likely doesnt contain what you think)

Comment: please update the question with a textual description of what you're trying to do; I'm *guessing* you want to match uuid's and print the associated ip, but you should explicitly state the objective as opposed to having us reverse engineer your code to determine the objective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- objective is to find matching uuid's and print with the associated ip address

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v qt="'" -v host="hostnameA" '

FNR==NR && $1=="value:"     { uuids[$2]; next }
FNR>=4  && !($0 ~ /------/) { split($0,a,"[[:blank:]]*[|][[:blank:]]*")
#                             print NR,FNR,$0
#                             for (i in a) print "a:" i ":" a[i] ":"

                              if (a[2] in uuids) {
                                 split(a[5],b,"=")
#                                for (i in b) print "b:" i ":" b[i] ":"

                                 if ( (host == "hostnameA") || (host == "hostnameB") ) {
                                    printf "ID == %s and IP == %s\n", a[2], b[2]
                                 }
                                 else
                                 if ( (host == "hostnameC") || (host == "hostnameD") ) {
                                    printf "ID == %s and IP == %s\n", a[2], b[2]
                                 }
                                 else { print "other" }
                              }
                            }
#END { print "###########"; for (i in uuids) print "uuids:" i ":" uuids[i] ":" }
' ids.yaml list.txt
```

**NOTES:**

- the order in which the files are fed to `awk` has been switched
- remove the `#'s` to have the script generate some debugging output; these are just some examples to give OP an idea of how to go about debugging their code

This generates:

```
ID == a4594fa2-5867-4fb1-b0d6-48833a750f10 and IP == 1.1.1.1
```

With the `#'s` removed:

```
7 4 | a4594fa2-5867-4fb1-b0d6-48833a750f10 | serverA                    | ACTIVE  | IP=1.1.1.1  | Debian11 | Airo B30G23 |
a:1::
a:2:a4594fa2-5867-4fb1-b0d6-48833a750f10:
a:3:serverA:
a:4:ACTIVE:
a:5:IP=1.1.1.1:
a:6:Debian11:
a:7:Airo B30G23:
a:8::
b:1:IP:
b:2:1.1.1.1:
ID == a4594fa2-5867-4fb1-b0d6-48833a750f10 and IP == 1.1.1.1
8 5 | 314d0d30-0836-4816-be75-310069d9c6ea | server B                   | ACTIVE  | IP=2.2.2.2  | Ubuntu20 | IAV B50C24  |
a:1::
a:2:314d0d30-0836-4816-be75-310069d9c6ea:
a:3:server B:
a:4:ACTIVE:
a:5:IP=2.2.2.2:
a:6:Ubuntu20:
a:7:IAV B50C24:
a:8::
9 6 | 4c82f347-b0a6-471d-87d2-59bdd1d0bae4 | server C.me                | ACTIVE  | IP=3.3.3.3  | Ubuntu20 | IAV B50C48  |
a:1::
a:2:4c82f347-b0a6-471d-87d2-59bdd1d0bae4:
a:3:server C.me:
a:4:ACTIVE:
a:5:IP=3.3.3.3:
a:6:Ubuntu20:
a:7:IAV B50C48:
a:8::
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm still learning `awk` and didn't know how to do that:( I see my attempt wasn't even close to the real answer you provided. I'll check the comments and answer them one by one.