# awk find and replace with regex and environment variable

Tags: bash, awk

This is my text:

```
    set $domain_name some-not-important-name.com;
```

I want to reach this:

```
    set $domain_name test.com;
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
DOMAIN_NAME=test.com
awk '{ sub(/ set $domain_name(.*)/, " set $domain_name $DOMAIN_NAME;") }1' file
```

current result:

```
    set $domain_name some-not-important-name.com
```

**Update 1**

The reason I added multiple `whitespaces` is that, the line belongs to `nginx` config and it has multiple spaces.

Since there are both `charset` and `set` in my file and they're not the first character of the line, so I should replace  `set` with space before.

Comment: What do you mean by "this is my text"? BTW, `DOMAIN_NAME` is not an environment variable, and parameter substitution does not occur between single quotes.

Comment: @user1934428 I mean this is the line I want to find and replace. Also, yes `DOMAIN_NAME` is a variable I set but is not an env-var. I also tried with double quotes but no luck.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `nginx` so .... do you need to maintain the *multiple whitespaces*?

Comment: @markp-fuso the `nginx` doesn't matter. Also it doesn't care if I have indentations or not, but for being more readable and having better blocks, I prefer to keep those spaces.

Comment: @Saeed : Probably you made a mistake with double-quoting. If you try something unsuccessfully, edit your question so that we can see your new attempt.

Comment: I'm surprised to see you trying to expand shell variables inside an awk script given all of the questions you've had answered and the fact you've done this the right way in some of your previous scripts (e.g. `-v host="${HOSTNAME,,}"` in https://stackoverflow.com/q/76851963/1745001). Anyway,- please read [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script).

Comment: @EdMorton somewhere I need to expand them, because it's required to use them. Shouldn't I use them? I may not notice your previous answers and comments carefully.

Comment: Just read that article I referred you too, it explains everything.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks, I read it, but `echo ${HOSTNAME,,}` prints hostname all in lowercase. Do you mean use like this? `lowercase_hostname=${HOSTNAME,,}`, then `awk -v host="$(lowercase_hostname)" ...` I tried `ENVIRON[...]`, but it's not an env-var. It's a user-defined var.

Comment: I think you're overthinking this. `-v x="$y"` sets an awk variable named `x` to the contents of a shell variable named `y`. To convert the contents of a shell variable to lower case you use `"${y,,}"` instead of just `"$y"`. So if you want the awk variable `x` to contain the contents of the shell variable `y` after being converted to lower case then you use `-v x="${y,,}"`.  So if you want an awk variable `dom` to contain the contents of the shell variable `DOMAIN_NAME` as-is, just write `-v dom="$DOMAIN_NAME"`

Comment: As that article I referenced shows you, if your shell variable isn't exported you can still access it through ENVIRON by puting it into the environment of the call to awk with (all on the same line) `y="$y" awk 'BEGIN{x=ENVIRON["y"]}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** (maintains spacing)

Setup:

```
$ cat file
ignore this line
    set    $domain_name    some-not-important-name.com;
ignore this line
```

One `awk` idea:

```
DOMAIN_NAME=test.com

awk -v dn="${DOMAIN_NAME}" '                                            # set awk variable "dn" to OS variable value
$1 == "set" && $2 == "$domain_name" { ndx = index($0,$3)                # find location of 3rd field
                                      $0  = substr($0,1,ndx-1) dn ";"   # rebuild current line
                                    }
1                                                                       # print all lines to stdout
' file
```

**Assumptions:**

- there are only 3 white-spaced delimited fields in the line of interest
- `$3` does not match the strings `set` nor `$domain_name`
- `$3` does not contain white space

This generates:

```
ignore this line
    set   $domain_name    test.com;
ignore this line
```

---

**Original answer:** (does not maintain spacing)

Setup:

```
$ cat file
ignore this line
    set    $domain_name    some-not-important-name.com;
ignore this line
```

Assuming the line of interest has just the 3 space-delimited fields ...

One `awk` idea:

```
DOMAIN_NAME=test.com

awk -v dn="${DOMAIN_NAME}" '
$1 == "set" && $2 == "$domain_name" { $3 = dn ";"}   # redefine the 3rd field as dn + ";"
1                                                    # print all lines to stdout
' file

# or as a one-liner:

awk -v dn="${DOMAIN_NAME}" '$1 == "set" && $2 == "$domain_name" { $3 = dn ";"} 1' file
```

This generates:

```
ignore this line
set $domain_name test.com;
ignore this line
```

Comment: Thanks, no problem. I add spaces in my bash file for that for a workaround.

Comment: Yep, assignment causes awk to recalculate fields removing whitespace. Substitution is the key.

Answer (score 3):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk -v dom="$DOMAIN_NAME" 'match($0,/^[[:space:]]*set[[:space:]]+\$domain_name[[:space:]]+/) { $0=substr($0,1,RLENGTH) dom ";"} 1' file
    set $domain_name test.com;
```

That will work and retain spacing no matter which characters/strings are present in the input line, including regexp metachars, backreferences, substrings of earlier fields, white space, or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
v=' set $domain_name some-not-important-name.com;'
awk -v d=test.com '{ sub(/ set \$domain_name .*/, " set $domain_name " d ";")}1' <<<"$v"
```

you have to escape the `$`

Comment: Thanks, but the variable `d` is not static in this case. It's a user-defined variable that may change in the future.